# xmpp framework to login different gateways like Gtalk using openfire id

Tags: frameworks, xmpp, gateways

How can I login different gateways like google and yahoo using xmpp framework. I am using openfire server. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTalk uses Xmpp, so you can chat between gtalk and openfire users using s2s federation (which should be on by default in openfire). Yahoo is it's own protocol and you'd need the IM gateway plug-in for openfire. However that seems to be deprecated and instead there is now the standalone IM gateway, [Kraken](http://kraken.blathersource.org/), which should do what you want